# Veeam backup and copy jobs reorganization to resolve out-of-space issue

Tags: vmware-esxi, backup-restoration, veeam, data-protection

I have two sites, one hosting the Veeam Management Server, the other hosting a Proxy. Both server have proxy and repository roles, and both are running one job to backup all production VMs of on-site ESXis.
Also, they are both running Copy jobs to move and retain all backups on local and distant site (GFS retention policy enabled).

Our goal is to kept a part of our production VMs for archive purpose , with maintaining protection for all of our production VMs.

I plan to re-organize our backup jobs and repositories, because the actual plan is consuming nearly all of our storage on repositories : all of our production VMs are kept with GFS retention policy.

So my plan is :

1. Create new repositories "Archives" (only new folders on same storage) on each sites, to split things for monitoring purpose.
2. Move all my backups and backups-copy files to those new repositories, then launch rescan on them.
3. Create new Backup jobs, with only part of our VMs which we want to archive, set the repository to our new "Archives" repos, then map moved backups to those jobs.
4. Create new Copy jobs for newly created backup jobs, with GFS retention enabled, and set 0 restore points to keep, retain backup locally and on the other site, set repository to our new "Archives" repos, then map moved backups-copy files to those jobs.
5. Remove production VMs to archive from originals Backup and Copy jobs (with repos rescan et backups re-maping).
6. Remove backups of production VMs (those not to be archived), from moved Copy jobs files that will retain data to be archived.

Does have I made mistakes, or forgot any step to clean original backups from data that we not want to archive ?

Regards,
Clément.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing right things. Just a few tips to consider before you start (if not too late). If you use incremental backup chains (not incremental-forever), then you should be able to free some space up by deleting previously used chain(s). In case of reverse incremental chain, it's even easier with deletion of the most outdated points.
General recommendation, that you use Backup Jobs for short-term backups (1 week - 1 month depending on your policies) and use Backup Copy Jobs to maintain long-term archival (GFS is an example).
If uncertain, review Veeam best practices towards retention policies and backup modes: https://veeampdf.s3.amazonaws.com/guide/veeam_best_practices_vmware.pdf

Comment: Thank you, this setup as also been validating by Veeam on support forum : https://forums.veeam.com/veeam-backup-replication-f2/veeam-backup-and-copy-jobs-reorganization-to-resolve-out-of-t36129.html#p204053